# Match starting and ending character using Java Matcher class

Tags: java, regex

I want to get words from string that starts with `#` and end with `space`. I've tried using this `Pattern.compile("#\\s*(\\w+)")` but it doesn't include characters like `'` or `:`.

I want the solution with only **Pattern Matching** method.

Comment: Try `Pattern.compile("(?U)#(\\S+)")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try matching using the pattern `(?<=\\s|^)#\\S+`, which would match any word starting with `#`, followed by any number of non whitespace characters.

```
String line = "Here is a #hashtag and here is #another has tag.";
String pattern = "(?<=\\s|^)#\\S+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}

#hashtag
#another
```

### Demo

Note: The above solution might give you an edge case of pulling in punctuation which appears at the end of a hashtag.  If you don't want this, then we can rephrase the regex to only match positive certain characters, e.g. letters and numbers.  But, maybe this is not a concern for you.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `\s` is `\S`, so you can use a regex like this:

```
#\s*(\S+)
```

Or for Java:

```
Pattern.compile("#\\s*(\\S+)")
```

It will capture anything that is not a white space.

See demo [here](https://regexr.com/3umm0).

If you want to stop on the space character and not any white space change the `\S` to `[^ ]`.
The `^` inside the brackets means it will negate whatever comes after it.

```
Pattern.compile("#\\s*([^ ]+)")
```

See demo [here](https://regexr.com/3umm6).